# Is it always faster to use string as key in a dict?

Tags: python

On this [page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), I see something interesting:

*Note that there is a fast-path for dicts that (in practice) only deal with str keys; this doesn't affect the algorithmic complexity, but it can significantly affect the constant factors: how quickly a typical program finishes.*

So what does it exactly mean?

Does it mean using string as the key is always faster?

If yes, why?

**Update:**

Thanks for the suggestions about optimization! But I'm actually more interested in the plain truth, than whether or when we should do optimization.

**Update 2:**

Thanks for the great answers, I'll cite the content from the [link](http://lewk.org/blog/python-dictionary-optimizations) provided by @DaveWebb here:

"
...

**ma_lookup** is initially set to the **lookdict_string** function (renamed to **lookdict_unicode** in 3.0), which assumes that both the keys in the dictionary and the key being searched for are standard PyStringObject's. It is then able to make a couple of optimiziations, such as mitigating various error checks, since string-to-string comparison never raise exceptions. There is also no need for rich object comparisons either, which means we avoid calling **PyObject_RichCompareBool**, and always use **_PyString_Eq** directly.

...
"

Also, for the experiment numbers, I think the size of the difference will be even bigger if there is no int-to-string conversion

Comment: I would guess this all comes down to how quickly the `__hash__` method of a key object is. I'm guessing that it is fairly simple to hash a string, but I would be very interested in what proportion of a dictionary lookup is spent hashing.

Comment: Your update doesn't change anything. No, it will not be faster in most cases unless your keys were strings in the first place.

Comment: @Lattyware the linked page seems to imply an increase in speed *for each lookup* not just for construction.

Comment: @Wilduck I'm not talking about construction. If your keys were not strings to begin with, every time you need to do a lookup, you will need to convert your key to a string. (Unless you are doing something trivial with the dictionary).

Comment: @Lattyware Ahh, I understand. Although I can still imagine cases where you could show an improvement from an upfront conversion of strings.

Comment: @Wilduck If you can think of a good scenario for it, SO encourages answering your own questions.

Comment: @Lattyware Not my question (just one that I found interesting) I may still formulate an answer, but it looks like Dave Web did a quick timeit.

Comment: @Wilduck Whoops, didn't notice that one. But yeah, as I say, if you can think of a good situation, put it in an answer - I can't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The C code that underlies the Python dict is optimisted for String keys.  [You can read about this here](http://lewk.org/blog/python-dictionary-optimizations) (and in the book the blog refers to).

If the Python runtime knows your dict only contains string keys it can do things such as not cater for errors that won't happen with a string to string comparison and ignore the rich comparison operators.  This will make the common case of the string key only `dict` a little faster.  (Update: timing shows it to be more than a little.)

However, it is unlikely that this would make a significant change to the run time of most Python programs.  Only worry about this optimisation if you have measured and found `dict` lookups to be a bottleneck in your code.  [As the famous quote says, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

The only way to see how much faster things really are, is to time them:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a["500"]','a ={}\nfor i in range(1000): a[str(i)] = i')
0.06659698486328125
>>> timeit.timeit('a[500]','a ={}\nfor i in range(1000): a[i] = i')
0.09005999565124512
```

So using string keys is about 30% faster even compared to `int` keys, and I have to admit I was surprised at the size of the difference.

Comment: Your test presumes there is no cost to getting `"500"` as opposed to `500` - which makes a huge difference - see my answer.

Comment: The question asked if string keys were always faster and my test was intended to show, which it did.  I don't think the question was asking about converting from another object to a string and using that as the key - which would be bad for a number of reasons - but rather simply if it was always worth using strings if the choice was available.

Comment: That's taking it out of context. There is no use to knowing that it's faster to use string keys if then any way that gets you string keys makes it slower.

Comment: I don't think your example proves that it's slow for "any way that gets you string keys".  An example that springs to mind is an employee object with a unique employee ID string attribute; an artificial example for sure, but it makes a point.  And as I said, if you are doing this kind of optimisation you would be measuring and comparing anyway.

Answer (score 10):

As this only affects the constant time, it's likely not to matter at all. The only time you really need to optimise is when you are working with very large data sets - which this does nothing to affect.

What this does mean is that in the cases where you have small dictionaries with strings as keys, Python will be quick - this is a common usage, so it's been optimised for.

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams points out, it's likely that converting your key to a string will cost (far) more than the slight boost you might gain from it being a string for the dict.

In short use what is relevant to your situation - optimisation should only be done where there is a need for it, not before.

Some tests:

```
python -m timeit -s "a={key: 1 for key in range(1000)}" "a[500]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0773 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "a={str(key): 1 for key in range(1000)}" "a[\"500\"]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0452 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "a={str(key): 1 for key in range(1000)}" "a[str(500)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.244 usec per loop
```

As you can see, while the string-based dict is faster, converting the key is very expensive by comparison, totally mitigating the gain (and then some).

So yes, if the data you are using is **only** being used as keys to the dictionary, and what format your store them in doesn't matter, then strings are preferable, in a small dictionary. In practice, that is a very rare case (and you'd probably be using strings already).

Comment: Especially since converting some types to a string can be more expensive than just using them as a key in the first place.

Comment: sorry, I guess I should modify my question

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Very true.

Comment: +1 for "use what is relevant to your situation." That being said, it would be very interesting to construct a situation where using only string keys shows a significant improvement. How extreme does the situation need to be?

Comment: @Wilduck As I say, it'll show the biggest gains in small dictionaries where the keys were meant to be strings in the first place. In any larger dict, the variable time factor will blot out the constant gain that this gives you. If you are converting to a string, that will negate any gains.