# Why are string keys in python dictionaries slower to write/read than tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

In trying to optimize the speed of a program that mimics a tree structure ("Tree" is stored in a DICT with Cartesian coordinate x,y coordinate pairs as keys) I have found that storing their unique addresses in a dictionary as a Tuple, rather than Strings, results in substantially faster run-time.

My question is, if Python is optimized for string keys in dictionaries and hashing, why is using Tuples so much faster in this example? String keys seem to take 60% longer in doing the exact same task. Am I overlooking something simple in my example?

I was referencing this thread as the basis for my question (as well as others that make the same assertion that strings are faster): [Is it always faster to use string as key in a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162201/is-it-always-faster-to-use-string-as-key-in-a-dict)

Below is the code I was using to test the methods, and time them:

```
import time

def writeTuples():
    k = {}
    for x in range(0,500):
        for y in range(0,x):
            k[(x,y)] = "%s,%s"%(x,y)
    return k

def readTuples(k):
    failures = 0
    for x in range(0,500):
        for y in range(0,x):
            if k.get((x,y)) is not None: pass
            else: failures += 1
    return failures

def writeStrings():
    k = {}
    for x in range(0,500):
        for y in range(0,x):
            k["%s,%s"%(x,y)] = "%s,%s"%(x,y)
    return k

def readStrings(k):
    failures = 0
    for x in range(0,500):
        for y in range(0,x):
            if k.get("%s,%s"%(x,y)) is not None: pass
            else: failures += 1
    return failures

def calcTuples():
    clockTimesWrite = []
    clockTimesRead = []
    failCounter = 0
    trials = 100

    st = time.clock()
    for x in range(0,trials):
        startLoop = time.clock()
        k = writeTuples()
        writeTime = time.clock()
        failCounter += readTuples(k)
        readTime = time.clock()
        clockTimesWrite.append(writeTime-startLoop)
        clockTimesRead.append(readTime-writeTime)

    et = time.clock()

    print("The average time to loop with tuple keys is %f, and had %i total failed records"%((et-st)/trials,failCounter))
    print("The average write time is %f, and average read time is %f"%(sum(clockTimesWrite)/trials,sum(clockTimesRead)/trials))
    return None

def calcStrings():
    clockTimesWrite = []
    clockTimesRead = []
    failCounter = 0
    trials = 100

    st = time.clock()
    for x in range(0,trials):
        startLoop = time.clock()
        k = writeStrings()
        writeTime = time.clock()
        failCounter += readStrings(k)
        readTime = time.clock()
        clockTimesWrite.append(writeTime-startLoop)
        clockTimesRead.append(readTime-writeTime)

    et = time.clock()
    print("The average time to loop with string keys is %f, and had %i total failed records"%((et-st)/trials,failCounter))
    print("The average write time is %f, and average read time is %f"%(sum(clockTimesWrite)/trials,sum(clockTimesRead)/trials))
    return None

calcTuples()
calcStrings()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your indentation correct for `readTuples` and `readStrings`?

Comment: try inspecting each function with `dis` and using `profile` or `timeit`. Add more information gained from these tests and it will be easier for us to help you. :)

Answer (score 5):

The tests are not fairly weighted (hence the timing discrepancies).  You are making twice as many calls to `format` in your `writeStrings` loop as in your `writeTuples` loop and you are making infinitely more calls to it in `readStrings`.  To be a fairer test you would need to make sure that:

- Both write loops only make one call to `%` per inner loop
- That `readStrings` and `readTuples` both make either one or zero calls to `%` per inner loop.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I made the changes you recommended, and when I make equal number of calls in the READ functions, and equal numbers in both inner write loops -- I see the string version is about 30% faster. I did not expect the formatting function would add that much time onto it.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the string formatting is the issue.

here's a **quick** version that pre-calculates all the strings...

on my machine, writing strings is about 27% faster than writing tuples.  write/reading is about 22% faster.

i just quickly reformatted & simplified your stuff into timeit.  if the logic were a bit different , you could calc the difference in reads vs writes.

```
import timeit

samples = []
for x in range(0,360):
   for y in range(0,x):
        i = (x,y)
        samples.append( ( i, "%s,%s"%i) ) 


def write_tuples():
    k = {}
    for pair in samples:
        k[pair[0]] = True
    return k

def write_strings():
    k = {}
    for pair in samples:
        k[pair[1]] = True
    return k


def read_tuples(k):
    failures = 0
    for pair in samples:
        if k.get(pair[0]) is not None: pass
        else: failures += 1
    return failures

def read_strings(k):
    failures = 0
    for pair in samples:
        if k.get(pair[1]) is not None: pass
        else: failures += 1
    return failures


stmt_t1 = """k = write_tuples()"""
stmt_t2 = """k = write_strings()"""
stmt_t3 = """k = write_tuples()
read_tuples(k)"""
stmt_t4 = """k = write_strings()
read_strings(k)"""


t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_t1, setup = "from __main__ import samples, read_strings, write_strings, read_tuples, write_tuples")
t2 = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_t2, setup = "from __main__ import samples, read_strings, write_strings, read_tuples, write_tuples")
t3 = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_t3, setup = "from __main__ import samples, read_strings, write_strings, read_tuples, write_tuples")
t4 = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_t4, setup = "from __main__ import samples, read_strings, write_strings, read_tuples, write_tuples")

print "write tuples       : %s" % t1.timeit(100)
print "write strings      : %s" % t2.timeit(100)
print "write/read tuples  : %s" % t3.timeit(100)
print "write/read strings : %s" % t4.timeit(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the difference in speed is due to the string formatting of the accessor key.

In writeTuples you have this line:

```
        k[(x,y)] = ...
```

Which creates a new tuple and assigns it's values (x,y), before passing to the accessor of k.

In writeStrings you have this line:

```
        k["%s,%s"%(x,y)] = ...
```

Which does all the same computations as in writeTuples but also has the overhead of parsing the string "%s,%s" (this might be done at compile time, I'm not sure) but then it also has to build a new string from the numbers (for example "12,15"). I believe it's this which increases the running time.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, the indentation in the real program was correct. Getting it into SO I keyed it in wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Easy to do. I've tweaked my answer to better reflect the "fixed" question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on a Core i5 1.8GHz machine and for the following results

- `0.076752` vs. `0.085863` tuples to strings for the loop
- write `0.049446` vs. `0.050731`
- read `0.027299` vs. `0.035125`

so tuples appear to be winning, but you're doing the string conversion twice in the write function. Changing `writeStrings` to

```
def writeStrings():
    k = {}
    for x in range(0,360):
        for y in range(0,x):
            s = "%s,%s"%(x,y) 
            k[s] = s
    return k
```

- `0.101689` vs. `0.092957` tuples to strings for the loop
- write `0.064933` vs. `0.044578`
- read `0.036748` vs. `0.048371`

The first thing to notice is that there's quite a bit of variation in the results, so you may want to change `trials=100` to something bigger, recall that python's `timeit` will do I think 10000 by default. I did `trials=5000`

- `0.081944` vs. `0.067829` tuples to strings for the loop
- write `0.052264` vs. `0.032866`
- read `0.029673` vs. `0.034957`

so the string version is faster but as already pointed out in other posts, it's not the dict lookup it's the string conversion that's hurting.